# is it necessary for all images to be of same size while using the tensorflow object detection api?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have a set of images(already labelled) which are of different resolutions and I wish to train these using the object detection api. Can I train it if all my images are of different sizes by specifying the `min_dimension` and `max_dimension` in the config file to be the greatest width and smallest height respectively?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not necessary for all images to be of same size while using the tensorflow object detection api.

You don't need to resize the training images. That is taken care by the script itself. Whatever dimensions your images are they are internally resized by the config file.

Here is a sample of ssdmobilenet config file

```
image_resizer {
  fixed_shape_resizer {
    height: 300
    width: 300
  }
```

The `image resizer` resizes all your images to 300x300 and takes them into training.

Further if you want high accuracy you can change these values from your config file as follows (please note doing this takes more time to train your model )

```
image_resizer {
  fixed_shape_resizer {
    height: 600
    width: 800
  }
```

Whatever values you choose to add to the image resizer be sure all your image dimensions are >= `image resizer` dimensions. Other wise you will get tensor shape mismatch error.

Comment: Are the bounding boxes also scaled accordingly when the images are resized?

Comment: Yes, bounding boxs are drawn based on normalized coordinates . It doesn't matter if the image is small or large. The box will cover the detected object (roi). If I answered your question please click on the tick mark button next to my above code. Thanks

Comment: I am using the faster_rcnn_resnet50 model for training. The config file contains the following code snippet.  
`keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 600
        max_dimension: 1024
      }`
What should I enter as the `min dimension` and `max dimension` in the config file ?

Comment: enter min_dimension 300 and max_dimension 300

Comment: The max width and min height among all my images are 257 and 44 respectively. So should I enter those values as max and min dimensions?

Comment: yes, only if width of all the images in your training dataset >= 257, and height of all training images >= 44

Comment: No, actually 257 is the max width and 44 is my min height of all the images. So, if I understand you correctly, `max_dimension` should be the min value of the width of all images and `min_dimension` should be the min value of the height of all images. Is this correct?

Comment: just dont overthink it really is so easy. every image you enter will be rescaled to value you enter in the config file. if your input image has less dimension width/height than what you entered in config file you will get error otherwise not.

Comment: i think if the images are disproportionately bigger than the dimension denoted from image resizer, there is a problem.(from my observation, i can be wrong) Also dpi needs to be consistent from an image to image.  Please correct me if I am wrong. The best case scenario from my short experience is that all images are identical in terms of dimension and dpi.